Expected Flips For Alice
Alice and Bob each have a coin and flip it until they get a heads. If Bob flipped his coin more times than Alice, what is the expected number of times Alice flipped her coin?
I found that the probability that Alice has 1 flip, whilst Bob has 2+ is $\frac{1}{4}$, probability that Alice has 2 flips, Bob has 3+ is $\frac{1}{16}$ and so on. Then
$E(A) = 1\times(\frac{1}{4}) + 2\times(\frac{1}{16}) + 3 \times (\frac{1}{64})...$
$E(A) = \frac{4}{9}$
However, the answer is $\frac{4}{3}$. What am I doing wrong?

You should be using conditional probabilities so that they add up to 1.

Extending the comment of @Karl, notice that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 4^{-k} = \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{4}{3} = \frac{1}{3}.$$
Since you are given that one of these events must have occured, you need to scale by
dividing by $~\dfrac{1}{3}.~$
See also conditional probability.
